# How to convert a console application to a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, console-application

How to convert a console application in C# to a windows service? Is there a template that does it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: What have you tried? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I did not get your question Console application and windows service are two different things.You want to add windows service in console application ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside of your code, you can use the Environment.UserInteractive property to determine which mode you are in console/service.

Example:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var service = new Service1();

        if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { service };
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Running as a Console Application");
        Console.WriteLine(" 1. Run Service");
        Console.WriteLine(" 2. Other Option");
        Console.WriteLine(" 3. Exit");
        Console.Write("Enter Option: ");

        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (input)
        {
            case "1":
                service.Start(args);
                Console.WriteLine("Running Service - Press Enter To Exit");
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case "2":
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Closing");
    }
}

public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1() { InitializeComponent(); }
    public void Start(string[] args) { OnStart(args); }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args) { }
    protected override void OnStop() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I often have my windows services run as console applications when built in debug mode to simplify debugging.

The most straightforward approach in your case is probably to create a new Windows Service to have the right structure of your main entry point and the correct references, then integrate your console app code into that structure.

Reading/Writing to/from the console will have to be rewritten.

If you have to read user input, consider alternative means to provide that input to the service.  If you write output to the console, write it instead to a log.  Personally I would recommend NLog.

Answer (score -3):

project's General properties -> change the type to Class Library.
you can remove the Main Function because it won't be called upon

Comment: The main function certainly is called in a Windows Service.